# Hide street names in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to do a game with a map. I need a map without the name of the streets on it. Is it possible to hide the name of the streets (but not its value) in Google Maps API (iOS, Android)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a json file in res/raw, called style_json.txt for example

In the file, put :

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then in your onMapReady :

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //your code
        try {
           boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
        //your code
    }
```

Source : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/poi
and : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features

Comment: @BaummitAugen is that better?

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this.)

Answer (score 0):

You need styling. You just need turn off all labels' visibility. However, as far as I know, there are no way for Google Maps iOS or Android API to style the map, yet.

You can do it with static maps, and the JavaScript API through.

This is an example on how to do it with static map.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.420988,-122.086891&zoom=17&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=element:labels|visibility:off